# Oracle BPM Suite REST Services

Tags: java, oracle, business-process-management, oracle-bpm-suite

Does anybody know how to call the REST API to get all Processes in Oracle BPM?

I already tried this without success:

```
http://bpm.server.com:7101/bpm/services/rest/processes
```

It only returns the string: "Processes.", but I need creation dates, name, id, etc...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It's seems that the Processes REST API is not implemented yet. Too bad.

It's is included in the WASL(/bpm/services/rest/application.wadl), but it returns  the string "Processes" instead of a JSON. Follow this [link](http://avioconsulting.com/blog/reviewing-oracle-bpms-new-rest-api) for more info.